# want to share passport.js session to root and other subdomains

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, session-cookies

I create the passport session on sub.domain.com.  I want to use this session on domain.com.

I tried setting session-cookie, like so:

```
app.use(
  session({
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      domain: 'domain.com'   // also tried '.domain.com'
```

The cookie that passport created always has sub.domain.com, and seems to ignore the above code all together.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to put the domain outside the cookie block:

```
app.use(
  session({
  domain: '.domain.com'  //!important
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      domain: '.domain.com'
```